# Why json_decode() return empty?

Tags: php, json, encode

I have this JSON string:

```
$json = '
{"id1":"x",
"N1":"x",
"T1":"x",
"E1":"x",
"E11":"x",
"O1":"x",
"C1":"x",
"C11":"x",
"F1":"x"},

{"id2":"x",
"N2":"x",
"T2":"x",
"E2":"x",
"E22":"x",
"O2":"x",
"C2":"x",
"C22":"x",
"F2":"x"}
';
```

and after I parse with PHP:

```
print_r(json_decode($json));
```

and you can see PHP return empty.

Any help, please...

Thanks

Comment: Passed via jsonlint.com - "Error: Parse error on line 11: Expecting 'EOF', got ','"

Comment: Basically the JSON isn't valid, and therefore `json_decode` returns `null` and cannot parse the JSON

Answer (score 5):

That's not really valid JSON syntax, if you intend that to be two objects, you need to put them in an array. 
Like `[
{your first object here},
{your next object}
]`